# Grid RowDefinitions trouble in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, grid, windows-phone-8

Critical problem here. In my case i assemble the below code for my application. Unfortunately, it creates the bigger problem in layout. Even we put RowDefinitions with Auto, it does not consider the RowHeight and goes underneath to the Bottom of the Windows Phone emulator.

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="firstGrid" Tap="FirstGrid_OnTap"/>
            <Grid Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Button Content="A"/>
                <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="B"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

On loading of the page, it fills the firstGrid with the ImageBrush. Hence whenever user taps on the firstGrid, It will just insert one more row to the Grid by enabling the visibility of the second grid. This second grid will have couple of buttons. I astonished when i see the second grid because it hides in the bottom of the emulator. Even my hundred of different attempts , i am not able dig into the main problem which actually it has. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve or what your problem is.

Comment: My second grid which has buttons right, that grid is not completely visible to the layout that's what the trouble here.

Comment: Your XAML doesn't provide enough information on what you're trying to achieve. Please consider drawing your idea and posting it here, otherwise it's hard to help you.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding u need to make this change in code first row should be auto and second  *.

```
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```